# show orders placed by members in a custom view (showing registered members)?

Tags: php, drupal, view

I have a custom view in my Drupal it has "Commerce KickStart", that view lists the registered members on the site, i want it to also show the orders made by each member.

How can i achieve that? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating 2 views

1. Displays registered users on the website
2. Displays the order details as per the uid

Then you can make use of [Viewfield](https://drupal.org/project/viewfield) module which will allow you to reference the second view from the first as a field.

Please read the documentation of the module